# Rollback sequence after unit test

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, spring-test

I'm running JUnit tests using spring-test, my code looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)  
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {})
@Transactional (propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
@Rollback
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository repository;

    @Before
    public void before() {
       //clean repository
    }

    @Test
    public void test_1() {
       //add new entity
    }   

    @Test
    public void test_2() {
      //add new entity
    } 
    ...  
}
```

I want to rollback my db in state before all tests. And tables rollbacks but sequence for id generation increases with each test.

Please help me to find the way to set sequence in start value before each test.

I'm using Spring, Hibernate, HsqlDb

Comment: You rather should use an embedded DB that is created and dropped between every test. Or at least create a new schema and drop it.

Answer (score 0):

If you call a method with @Transactional you can't make a rollback. What you can do is an @After in order to drop all the database, and in a @Before create it again. I think it's not a very good idea, you should drop the values in order to isolate each test. I recommend you to use H2 database in order to be able to use in memory storage, so you don't have to worry about the id number.

You have to add this dependency to the pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.193</version>
</dependency>
```

And the configuration inside the .xml should be something like this:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:h2:mem:testDB;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Of course you should adapt it to your system, but you must keep that username and password in order to connect successfully.

If you don't want to auto create the tables, you could add this parameter on the connection URL:

```
INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:scripts/create.sql
```

and this will run your script before the tests.

Then in your tests you could do something link this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)  
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {})
@Transactional (propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void test_1() {
       //add new entity
    }   

    @Test
    public void test_2() {
      //add new entity
    } 

    @After
    public void tearDown(){
      repository.clean();
    }
}
```

And the clean method could be something like this

```
public void clean(){
    for (T obj: this.findall()) //replacing T for the type if you don't use generics
        session.delete(obj); //your entity manager or session, depending on how you do the queries
}
```